# How to run a command on each line of a multi line string variable in bash?

Tags: bash

The variable `$type` is a multi line string variable containing:

```
car
plane
```

You can get the output above issuing `echo "$type"`.

And I have a `some_command` that uses `$type` as one of its parameters.

**In bash, how would you execute `some_command` so that it runs with each line of `$type` one after another?** i.e. first `some_command` would run using `car` and then it would run again using `plane` and then the loop would stop once the line was empty i.e. no values left to execute `some_command` with.

Comment: What have you tried? What research did you make? Literally https://www.google.com/search?&q=bash+execute+command+for+each+line+in+file with maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775548/how-to-pass-the-value-of-a-variable-to-the-stdin-of-a-command ...

Comment: @KamilCuk I have been looking all over stack overflow and playing around with various loops but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (in my opinion) is to use `xargs` with argument `-L` (limit):

```
echo "$type" | xargs -L 1 some_command
```

`xargs` takes each input line and passed the value as an argument to `some_command`.

`some_command` may have other arguments too. `xargs` adds the input line at the end of its arguments list and executes it.

*On macOS it can be told to insert the input line into a different position by using `-J` but this is a non-standard FreeBSD extension that is not available in the GNU version of `xargs` (the version usually present on the Linux systems.)*

Comment: Are you sure that `-J` is a valid option for `xargs`?

Comment: @gshpychka I found today that `-J` is a FreeBSD extension and is available only on macOS. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the lines in `$type` do not contain white spaces other than the new line chars, try:

```
for line in $type; do echo working on "$line"; some_command "$line"; done
```

It is important not to surround the first occurence of `$type` with double quotes in the **for** statement, otherwise you will get all the lines at once.

Comment: I get the following output: ```working on car```, ```cut: car: no such file or directory```, ```working on plane```,```cut: plane: no such file or directory```

Comment: I removed the error using ```<<< "$line"``` but now all I get as output is ```working on car```, ```car```, ```working on plane```,```plane``` instead of the result of ```some_command```

Comment: If I run it as ```for line in $type; do echo working on "$line"; some_command; done``` i.e. without ```<<< "$line"``` then the result of ```some_command``` is somewhat correct. It displays ```working on car```, ```bgf```,```ged``` (which are the expected results of the grep command) but then it goes on to display ```working on plane```, and then ```bgf```,```ged``` again.

Comment: I think the error comes from the command `some_command` but since I have absolutely no idea of what that command is doing, I cannot tell you what is happening. From the diagnostics I see above, I suppose `some_command` is a bash script calling `cut` . Tell me please what `some_command car` does gives as output.

Comment: If you don't post the code of `some_command`, at least a simplified version of it, it will be hard to understand what is happening.

Comment: ```some_command``` is ```grep "$type,$part,$area" test.csv | cut -d, f4``` So based on the parameter values this is extracting from a .csv the value in the 4th column corresponding to the parameter values

Comment: I figured out the answer.